# What format is this, and how do I convert a byte array into this string format?

Tags: format, string-formatting, data-conversion

I need to edit (change) the image stored in a .resx file that is attached to a Winforms form (actually, it is being loaded into a textbox on an ***Active Reports*** (AR) report designer).

The current image is in the xml *.resx file as shown in the code snippet below
(*This is just the first few lines of the image in the xml resx file*):

```
<data name="textboxName.ImageBytes" type="System.Byte[], mscorlib">
    <value>&#xD;
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAADyUAAAImCAYAAABHbbdCAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACx&#xD;
jwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAAXEUAAFxFAbktYiwAAAAGYktHRAD/AP8A/6C9p5MAAAAHdElNRQffBBsQ&#xD;
Gwt/5sNmAAD/gElEQVR4XuzdO5gX1f0/8HDb5S5yk4vInYBcBJGLNxRFUVEEA4ICKiCgBAEFCUi6&#xD;
VKlSpftVqVKlS5UqVbpUqVKlS5UqVar9zzFj/sg5wF6+3++cM/N6Pc/7+Syo7DlnxmV29nxmfgIA&#xD;
ADAIX3311Znjx4//++WXXx5Zv379yGOPPTYyderUkeofjTrDw8Mjy5cvH3nmmWdGDhw4MHLy5Ml/&#xD;
fP311weqf9ZJFy9e/HVVUmsFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB5OnXq1F+fffbZkZkzZ6YaZQeSSZMmjSxb&#xD;
....
```

This is then loaded into an image on the form (the text box on the AR report designer).

Can someone tell me what format this is? and how to convert the byte array I have generated from the new image (that I need to replace this with), into this format?

Comment: Probably XML with some base64. Common in Microsoft products. They're not designed to be edited. Instead you're expected to already have the original image and design code.

Comment: I have the resx file with the old image in it, as [partially] shown. I have the new image that needs to be saved into the resource file, and the byte array for that new image, created by saving a screen shot of the image as a *,pnp file. (I could also get a byte array of the gif for the image). Buthow do I convert the byte array into bade64 hexadecimal string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a base64 format. To convert String in this format in C# use the code below (compite the code in a C#):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         //convert string to base64:
    string STR = "my string";
    byte[] VALUE1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(STR);
    string Valuebase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(VALUE1);
    Console.WriteLine(Valuebase64);


   //convert base64 em String: 
    string Valueinbase64 = "bXkgc3RyaW5n";
    byte[] VALUE2 = System.Convert.FromBase64String(Valueinbase64);     
    string someString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(VALUE2);       
    Console.WriteLine(someString);

        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Need to do this in C#....

Comment: Need add library:

using System.Text;

Comment: Tried this... It generated a string that was one line... The sample has multiple lines... with a unicode CR LF at the end of each one... Will that cause a problem in a resx file?

Comment: Tried this and it worked!  
Thanks so much!

Comment: the conversion is complete. This ending is the number formed by sequence of zero in binary. When returning the conversion goes back to the exact original data.